# Unable to get a Drop down to propagate more than once in a table

Tags: php, for-loop, drop-down-menu

Building a table with several Drop downs.
For one  I want to have a drop down with all the names from the query.
I almost have it but it only propagates for the first row, all other rows are are empty for for the name drop down.

Try as I might I am unable to see where the break down is.
Can someone  let me know where I am going wrong?

```
$query="select  index_member, name from members where active=1 order by name";
            $rs=$db->query($query);
            if($rs === false) {
                trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $db->error, E_USER_ERROR);
            }else {
            $rows_returned = $rs->num_rows;
            }
            echo $rows_returned;

echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Rank</th><th>Name</th><th>Town Hall</th><th>Experience</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
            for ($count=1 ;$count<=$rows_returned;$count++){
                echo "<tr><td>";
                echo $count;
                echo "</td>";
// !!!!!!!! the names iterate only for first row instead of each row!!!!!!!
                echo "<td>";
                    echo "<select name='Name'>";
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
                            echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name']."</option>";
                        }
                    echo "</select>";
                echo "</td>";


                echo "<td>";
                    echo "<select name='TH'>";
                        for ($th=3;$th<=10;$th++){
                            echo '<option value="'.$th.'">'.$th."</option>";
                        }   
                    echo "</select>";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo "<input type='number' name='EXP'>";
                echo "</td>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }   
            echo "</table>";
```